# How to return the value using tkinter oop?

Tags: python, tkinter

At the below code , I had the variable done, minute and second. When the button on tkinter   clicked ,  the variable done will pass the value 1 to set_timer_counter_process()  function to run the clock. While , the minute and second variable are passing the minute value and second value to the set _timer_counter_process() parameters which are minute and second . For example, will the button on GUI press, the done allow counter automatically run . At the same time , the variable minute and second will pass the value 1 minute zero second to the timer counter.

Problem:

I try to pass the value when the button pressed. However, the done variable seem to be always 1 . It should only equal to 1 after the button is pressed. While, the minute and second variable not passed to the set_timer_counter_process() function

code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 


class graphic(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.done = 0
        self.minute = 0 
        self.second = 0 
        self.title('Automation Cleaning Process')
        self.geometry('1000x800+100+100')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.set_button()
        self.set_text_gui()
        self.set_timer_counter_process(self.minute,self.second)

      


    def set_button(self):
        self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Automation Process',command=self.button_2_clicked_clock_counting_down, width = 50)
        self.button_2.place(x=380,y=300)
        
    
    def button_2_clicked_clock_counting_down(self): 
     self.done = 1 
     self.minute = 1 
     self.second = 0 
     self.button_2_value = 2
     print (self.button_2_value)
     print ("button 2 click ")
     return self.done, self.minute , self.second

    def set_text_gui(self): 
        self.time_title = tk.Label(self, text = "Time Process:", font=("Arial",30))
        self.time_colon= tk.Label(self, text = ":", font=("Arial",30))
        self.min_label= tk.Label(self, text = "min", font=("Arial",30))
        self.second_label=tk.Label(self, text = "sec", font=("Arial",30))
        self.label_minute = tk.Label(self,font=("Arial",30))
        self.label_second = tk.Label (self,font=("Arial",30))
        self.label_minute_zero_add = tk.Label(self,font=("Arial",30))
        self.label_second_zero_add = tk.Label(self,font=("Arial",30))
        # position label 
        

        self.time_title.place(x=80,y=630) 
        self.time_colon.place(x = 230 , y = 700)
        self.min_label.place(x=150,y=700)
        self.second_label.place(x=335,y=700)
        self.label_minute.place(x = 120 , y = 700)
        self.label_second.place(x=  278 , y = 700)
        self.label_minute_zero_add.place(x=  90 ,y=700)
        self.label_second_zero_add.place(x = 250 ,y= 700)

    def set_timer_counter_process(self,minute,second): 
        self.label_minute['text'] = minute
        self.label_second['text'] = second
        check_minute_length = len(str(minute))
        check_second_length = len(str(second))
        print(check_second_length)
        if check_minute_length == 1: 
            self.label_minute_zero_add['text'] = 0 
        else: 
            self.label_minute_zero_add['text'] =''

        if check_second_length == 1:
            self.label_second_zero_add['text'] = 0  
        else:
            self.label_second_zero_add['text'] ='' 

        if self.done == 1:      
            if second  > 0 :
                second = second - 1       
            elif second >= 0 :
                if minute > 0:
                    minute  = minute - 1  
                    second  = 60 
                else:
                    self.done = 0
        self.after(1000, self.set_timer_counter_process, minute , second) 
        

User_graphic = graphic()
User_graphic.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `True/False` for booleans, not `0/1`.

Comment: The return value of functions called from `command=func` is not used. There's no point in returning something from `button_2_clicked_clock_counting_down`.

Comment: I don't see any way that `self.done` can always be `1`. It should only be 1 after you click button 2.

Comment: oh yeah , you right . no point of use the return

Comment: For the minute and second variable passing. Is there a way i can pass the new value to the set_timer _counter_process() everytime button click ? . The time stay zero minute and zero second even when the button click the second and minute should appear 1 minute on GUI

Comment: You're passing them correctly. But why do you need to pass them, just set `self.second`, `self.minute` and you can use them in the other method.

Comment: I want the timer counter reset the counting time to 1 minute  when the user press the button and continue the  timer counter process afterward. Is there a way I can reset the counter when the button pressed

Comment: I think you're passing them correctly in `self.after()`. So probably some other logic is wrong. You should be decrementing the minute when second is less than 0.